# Present Continuous with Adverbial Clauses

Tags: adverbial-phrases

I heard present continuous is also used for temporary events which must not be happen in the same time with 'saying' but the first sentence below sounds wrong to me , even leaving work when he starts his shift is a temporary event for mentioned week .

Could you please tell me which one is correct ?

1- In this week , I am leaving work when my collegue starts his shift

2-In this week , I leave work when my collegue starts his shift

Answer (score 1):

[In English, we often use the present continuous for plans or arrangements.](http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous-future-arrangements/)  For example,

> We are going to the movies tomorrow.

It doesn't explicitly have anything to do with whether the event is temporary or not, only with whether it's a plan.  Because the speaker is describing a plan for the week, "I am leaving work" sounds natural.

(As an aside, "In this week" is incorrect; we would just start the sentence with "This week...")

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use 'I am leaving'

We often use the **present continuous/progressive tense** to talk about the **future**. The future actions and events are already decided. They are planned, or they are starting to happen.

I am seeing him next week. He is coming this month. She is meeting him this afternoon. They are having a party very soon. We are playing cricket the day after tomorrow. What are you doing this evening?

**this week** (NOT in this week)

We say- this week, this month, this year, next week, next month, next year, this morning, this afternoon, last Monday, this Wednesday, next Saturday etc.